# What is the necessity of declaring <packaging> in Maven POM file?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I made a Maven project and declared packaging as war.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

But this returned an error,

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (make-assembly) on project WaterDealer: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single failed: For artifact {ArtifactName:ArtifactName:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:war}: An attached artifact must have a different ID than its corresponding main artifact.`

But when I removed packaging declaration, everything worked just as expected.

Is there any specific reason for this happening? Why did declaring packaging type return an error `An attached artifasct must have a different ID than its corresponding main artifact.` ? How are they related?

I went through POM reference from this link [Maven POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) but did not find the information very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is from the assembly plugin which is not directly related to the packaging.

the packaging defines the type of artifact produced by maven (in general: one pom.xml one artifact - there are exceptions to this rule, e.x. sources jars or javadocs).

the default is "jar". so if you do not specify anything maven will create a jar file.

The other available values for [packaging](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) should be a bit self explaining?

The error might be simply the name that results. So packaging jar will create a jar file, "war" will create a war file and so on. If your assembly plugin creates a war file that may conflict with the war created through the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

The packaging defines some of the binding which are done. This means if you decide to use `packaging war` it means to run maven-war-plugin in the package phase. [This can be read in the appropriate documentation.](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-core/default-bindings.html)

The question is why you using maven-assembly-plugin in a war module and apart from that why using such an old version. Take a look on this site which shows the uptodate versions of the plugins:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/